# How can I combine two columns and search in it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
-- users
+----+--------+--------+
| id | f_name | l_name |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | Jack   | Smith  |
| 2  | Peter  | Hall   |
| 3  | John   | Price  |
+----+--------+--------+
```

And this is my query:

```
SELECT u.*,
       match(f_name) against(:input) f_name_order,
       match(l_name) against(:input) l_name_order,
       match(f_name, l_name) against(:input) both_order,
FROM users u
WHERE match(f_name, l_name) against(:input) 
ORDER BY both_order * 4 DESC, l_name_order * 2 DESC, f_name_order DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Now I want to select the last row of the table when the input is `john pri`. My current query doesn't match it. How can I do that?

Comment: can you run subquery maybe? select concat in sub query and then match on the concatenated column from subquery?

Answer (score 0):

you could use concat and like

```
select u.*
from users u 
where concat(f_name, ' ', l_name) like concat('%', :input, '%')
```

Comment: Can't I do that through *full-text* way?

Comment: looking to you sample  .. i'm suppose the full-text way is not useful ..  .. anyway  .. try  ..  and let me know